# Multiplicativity of $\zeta$-function regularized determinant

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, operator-theory, physics

Let $A$ be a selfadjoint elliptic differential operator on a compact manifold. In mathematical physics and differential topology one often defines its determinant using the [$\zeta$-function regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) which will be denoted below by $\det_\zeta(A)$.

**QUESTION.** Let $A,B$ be two commuting selfadjoint elliptic differential operators. Then their product $AB$ is also selfadjoint and elliptic. Is it true that
$\det_\zeta(AB)=\det_\zeta(A)\det_\zeta(B)?$

This question is closely related to this one [$\zeta$-function regularized determinants](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263012/zeta-function-regularized-determinants)

Comment: No. There's a paper on this by Kontsevich and Vishik, called DETERMINANTS OF ELLIPTIC PSEUDO-DIFFERENTIAL OPERATORS.